# Web Scraping --- an error occurred while processing this directive

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the table in the following [website](http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/7day_frcst/index.html):

It gives me `"[an error occurred while processing this directive]"`

It was working till yesterday and started throwing an error. I tried `"URLDownloadToFile"` and `"HTTPResponseStream"` within `VB.net` code but both throw the same error.

Any thoughts? I am not programming on the server side. It is a simple web/screen scrape.

Adding Code Snippet -

```
    Dim web_address As String
    'web_address = "http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/7day_frcst/index.html"
    web_address = "http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/csvdocs/seven_day_forecast2012-07-27-10-13.csv"

    'Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(web_address)
    'Dim myReq_response As Net.HttpWebResponse
    'myReq_response = myReq.GetResponse()
    'Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = New StreamReader(myReq_response.GetResponseStream) 'Imports System.IO
    Dim strng As String
    'strng = sr.ReadToEnd()


    Dim fileDownloadReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim fileDownloadResponse As HttpWebResponse
    ' fileDownloadReq = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(web_address)
    'fileDownloadReq.Method = "get"
    ' fileDownloadResponse = fileDownloadReq.GetResponse


    'Get the data from the page
    'Dim stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileDownloadResponse.GetResponseStream())
    'strng = stream.ReadToEnd()
    'fileDownloadResponse.Close()

    Dim genscapeDataFile As Long
    Dim raw_file_path As String
    raw_file_path = "C:\NEPOOL\ISONE_Seven_day_Raw.csv"
    genscapeDataFile = URLDownloadToFile(0, web_address, raw_file_path, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Without some code it will be very hard doing by guessing ... I'm not a soothsayer.

Comment: Added code snippet. It has three different ways of scraping the site none of which worked, hence the code commenting.

Answer (score 0):

It's an error in the hosting web page, not in your code. Whenever you have inexplicable issues like this, you should navigate directly to the page, if possible, and verify that it is working as you expect.

If you do navigate to this page in IE, you will see the same error message.

Comment: I can actually navigate to the page without any errors. I also tested downloading the CSV and it displayed fine. So I am not sure what you are pointing to.

Comment: I used the uncommented URL in your code, http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/csvdocs/seven_day_forecast2012-07-27-10-13.csv, and got this error. Are you using a different URL?

Comment: This one works fine and it is the same in the above post. http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/csvdocs/seven_day_forecast2012-07-27-10-13.csv

Comment: This works too                                            http://iso-ne.com/sys_ops/op_frcstng/7day_frcst/index.html